# Using Regular Expression to extract 4 digits from a string?

Tags: sql, regex, regexp-replace, master-data-management

Hoping for some help. I am new to regex and I am trying to come up with something that will search a string and check if it has 4 consecutive digits, and if so extract that 4 digit number into a new attribute.

I want to use a regular expression, but I'm a bit confused with the expression. 
For some background, I'm using a master data management tool that has it's own syntax quite similar to SQL.

This is the framework of the expression from the tool:
`REGEXP_LIKE(string, pattern, parameter)`

Something like `(string,/d/d/d/d,[,i])` ?

Pulling 4 digits from the string, not case sensitive (not sure if that would even be applicable)

Sometimes the location of the digits are different, so a substring isn't the best option here.

Any feedback would be helpful to get me in the right direction!

Comment: `\d{4}` will match 4 digits.

Comment: Read the regex tutorial at regular-expression.info.

Comment: What should happen if there's a substring of more than 4 digits?

Comment: @davidgeorge . . . Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the expression `(\d{4})` that will match any occurrence of 4 digits in a row in a string. `\d` refers to the set of `0-9` and the `{4}` is to specify 4 digits. If you want to be 4 or less you'd say `\d{,4}`. I'd also recommend checking out a website like https://regexr.com/, you can make expressions and then copy them elsewhere, and it shows a step by step on what each element means, and allows you to test it right there, and has a detailed cheat sheet about each feature. The parentheses around the expression specify that it is a group, so you can later receive the contents of it by getting the first group, witch whatever API you are using.